# How to use graphite in combination with logstash in a spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, logstash, graphite

I'd like to know if there exists some best practice how to chain graphite and logstash in a spring boot application. Should they exchange happen via the log files, or directly or is there some other way?
How would the respective setup look like, i.e. if we user docker and io.fabric maven plugin.